# how to replace single float dot with 0 using regex

Tags: regular-expression, python

i am working on python script and at some point of code i ask the user to input some integer or float number and i use regex to validate if he input the right value

Here is the input part of my script:

```py
import re

ask = input('Please enter some number or float: ')
match = re.match('\d+\.\d+|\d+', ask)
if match:
   print(match.group())
else:
   print('[!] Invalid value !')
```

Now if the user enter float `22.` the match will be `22` but i want it to be `22.0`

And if he enter `.22` then the match will be `None` but i want it to be `0.22`

How i can do this using regex ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match numbers where there might not be digits before or after the comma, you'll need a regex like `\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+`.

Basically, there's four different cases:

```
123
123.456
123.
.456
```

You can't make both the integer and fractional part optional, since the dot is also optional, and the lone dot probably shouldn't be accepted anyway.

We need at least two alternatives. `\d+(\.\d*)?` matches a number with an integer part, followed optionally by a dot and zero or more digits in the fractional part, so the first three cases. The second part matches the last case, that starts with the dot and has some digits after it.

That still returns `.22` and `22.` as they are, but you can easily add a check to see if the dot is the first or last character and add the missing zero. E.g. with `re.sub()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re, sys
m = re.match("^(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$", sys.argv[1])
if not m: 
    print("no match")
    exit(1)

s = m.group()
print(s)
s = re.sub("^\.", "0.", s);
s = re.sub("\.$", ".0", s);
print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! :)

Comment: Is there a way to add the missing zero within regex like replace the white space before or after dot with 0 ?

Comment: @Ahmed, not with that single regex, but you could use `re.sub()` to add the zero in front/behind a leading/trailing dot in the matched string, see edit